# VB.Net Interop Excel Com Exception

Tags: vb.net, excel, com, interop

This code was working perfect for quite a while till now,

It throws exception :

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'System.__ComObject' to class type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.WorksheetClass'

```
Dim ds_allJobs As DataSet = DBHandling.searchJob("", "", "all open jobs")
Dim xlApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

xlApp.Visible = False
xlApp.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet)
Dim xlWorksheet = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'IT FAILS HERE
xlWorksheet.Name = "Open Jobs"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: does the issue is present on different machines? the error is the same for different version of Excel? are you bound to or expect a specific version of Excel?

Comment: The exception does not appear to match the code.  The code as posted is bad, you cannot use the `New` operator to create a Worksheet.  Use `As` instead of `New`.

Comment: Problem was that I set the settings down to .Net 3.0.. thx guys

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you specify the types of objects (e.g. `exWorkbook As Excel.Workbook`)

Here is a way to make a new worksheet:

```
'create a new excel application (window)
Dim exApp As New Excel.Application
'add a workbook to it, and take a look at the first worksheet
Dim exWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = exApp.Application.Workbooks.Add()
'create a new worksheet
Dim exWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
'add this worksheet to the current applicatoin
exWorksheet = CType(exApp.Worksheets.Add(), Excel.Worksheet)
```

Doe this answer your question? The last line is Casting the object to type worksheet.